# How to delete the repeated data of txt using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to delete the repeat data in the flowing. Then ascending order according to the first column. Could you show the detail code to solve this problem? thank you very much.

```
  15.0    0.8     1.6    -0.0    -0.3  
  16.0    2.4    -0.2     0.1    -0.1  
  17.0    2.6    -0.6     0.2     0.2
  18.0    4.6     1.0     0.3     0.1
  19.0    2.3     1.4     0.9     0.2
  20.0    2.4     0.9     0.5     0.4


   6.0    5.8     2.5    -1.8    -1.9
   7.0    4.1     4.1    -0.8     1.6
   8.0    2.8     2.3     2.2    -0.5
   9.0   -1.5    -1.9     1.1     0.9
  10.0    0.9     0.2     0.0     0.1  

   9.0   -1.5    -1.9     1.1     0.9
  10.0    0.9     0.2     0.0     0.1
  11.0    2.3    -3.6     0.7    -0.6
  12.0   -1.2    -0.4    -0.2    -0.1
  13.0   -4.4     0.3    -0.3    -0.2
  14.0   -0.9     0.9    -0.4    -0.4
  15.0    0.8     1.6    -0.0    -0.3
```

Comment: A very frequent question on StackOverflow is http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: you mean in the file itself, or within a matrix?

Comment: @Nishant Thank you very much for helping me edit the format.could you tell me how to set the space between two data?

Comment: @Curie It's just in code block. See here http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) of `unique`, we find that the `unique(B, 'rows')` command will

- output unique rows only
- sort the output

So:

```
B = [...
    your data here
];

C = unique(B, 'rows');
```

will solve both your problems: the default for `sort` is to sort down the first column.